# Oracle SQL Enum replacement (Not in Pl SQL)

Tags: oracle, enums, oracle-apex, constants

I know this has been asked before, but none of the answers are currently satisfy me.

I need any kind of method / system which simulates the use of Enum / constants.

The idea is to retrieve the value like this:

```
Days.sunday      -- this will give the value 1
```

The background implementation can be complicated but the usage must stay simple. What I mean by simple is exactly as the example above, and not with long select statements and such.

I tried the use of functions, tables with nested table as row types and more, but all include non simple usage, or refer to pl sql.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what you are saying. Where exactly would you put/write that `Days.sunday` thing, press ENTER (I presume) and get `1` as result? Operating system prompt? SQL*Plus? TOAD? Oracle Apex SQL Workshop? Something else?  How would you then use that result?

Comment: Have you looked at CONTEXTs.  In the case above, you would refer to:   SYS_CONTEXT('DAYS','SUNDAY')

Comment: @Littlefoot I would use it in Oracle Apex, and also in PL SQL. In PL SQL I will be using it for example, with CASE / IF statements (if day = Days.sunday). In Apex it can be used to show value or process it to show something else.

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald I don't really know about CONTEXT, but from reading about it, seems like it is used more for other purposes (?)

Comment: A context is just a set of key/value pairs ... you can use it how you see fit

Answer (score 0):

I'm referring to the following:

- you tried functions
- all include non-simple usage or PL/SQL

Oracle *speaks* SQL and its procedural extension, PL/SQL. I'm not talking about Java nor different precompilers as I don't know much (or should I rather say *anything*) about these nor JavaScript (you can use in Oracle Apex).

So, if you want to make something happen, you do have to put some effort and write some code using SQL or PL/SQL. "Enumerator" like `days.sunday` can't just *exist* out of nowhere.

The way I understood the question, after reading comments you posted, leads to this option: a PL/SQL package with bunch of simple functions. Implementation isn't that complicated and usage is as simple as you wanted. See if it helps.

First, I'll set environment so that Sunday is day #1 (in my country, Monday is #1).

```
SQL> alter session set nls_territory = 'INDIA';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> select to_char(date '2020-05-31', 'd'  ) day_number,
  2         to_char(date '2020-05-31', 'day') day_name
  3  from dual;

D DAY_NAME
- ---------
1 sunday

SQL>
```

OK; this is the last Sunday, 31st of May 2020. Now, package:

```
SQL> create or replace package days as
  2    function sunday    return number;
  3    function monday    return number;
  4    function tuesday   return number;
  5    function wednesday return number;
  6    function thursday  return number;
  7    function friday    return number;
  8    function saturday  return number;
  9  end;
 10  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body days as
  2    function sunday    return number is begin return 1; end;
  3    function monday    return number is begin return 2; end;
  4    function tuesday   return number is begin return 3; end;
  5    function wednesday return number is begin return 4; end;
  6    function thursday  return number is begin return 5; end;
  7    function friday    return number is begin return 6; end;
  8    function saturday  return number is begin return 7; end;
  9  end;
 10  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

Looks quite simple, don't you think?

Finally, let's use it the way you commented (note line #4):

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    day number := to_char(date '2020-05-31', 'd');
  3  begin
  4    if day = days.sunday then
  5       dbms_output.put_line('It is Sunday');
  6    else
  7       dbms_output.put_line('It is not Sunday');
  8    end if;
  9  end;
 10  /
It is Sunday

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```